# how can I return from an asynchronous protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I have created an asynchronous protractor test, but am unsure when I should call the done() function?  How can I determine when all of the subfolders in the each loop has completed?  If you see my code below, you can see that I have placed the done() obviously in the incorrect location.  Can anyone tell me how / where I should place the done?

```
it('should make sure that there are no edit or delete buttons beside subfolders',function(done){
    folderContentPg.subFolders.each(function(subFolder){
        //get fid of subfolder
        subFolder.getAttribute('fid').then(
            function(subFolderFid){
                expect(folderContentPg.subFolderDeleteBtn(subFolderFid).isPresent()).toBe(false);
                expect(folderContentPg.subFolderEditBtn(subFolderFid).isPresent()).toBe(false);

            }
        );
        done();    
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `done()` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `done` callbacks. Protractor uses promises and [WebDriver's controlFlow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) to handle execution.